# Need to do a find & replace of link tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

So we have a site that allows content from users to be submitted, however, many users are not following the instructions when adding links to their content (it's a job board site).

The issue is we're ending up with:

```
<a href="">www.test.com</a>
```

Is there a way to have jQuery go through the text of an entire DIV and take whatever is in-between the  tags and place it inside the href?

I can't seem to figure out how to grab what's in-between those tags.

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: For all of the `<a>` tags, or just those with an empty `href` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
$('a').attr('href', function () {
    return 'http://' + $(this).text()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wr6mtksr/)**

Comment: might also consider parsing the text to see if protocol already exists

Comment: One more question: how would I check if the link is an email address so that in the href it puts it as "mailto:jane@test.com"?

Comment: That could be more complex; you might want to start a new question for that as it might require a regex depending on how specific you want to get with your email detection.